# jQuery plugins: best practise for making options persist

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Say I write a Plugin

```
<div id="myContainer">
   <input type="file" class="plugins-file">
</div>
```

While doing `$('#myContainer').hideFile();` the Plugin hides the input field and give the container a blue background, whatever.

I want to make the input field's class to be customizable.

So, while the standard is `plugins-file` I want to make shure the following is possible:

```
<div id="myContainer">
   <input type="file" class="custom-class">
</div>
```

And

```
$('#myContainer').hideFile({
    class: 'custom-class'
});
```

What is a good way to do it? (See this pen https://codepen.io/chrispillen/pen/WMOYKd)

Example:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.showLinkLocation = function(arg) {

      var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.showLinkLocation.defaults);

        if (typeof arg === "string" && arg === "test") {
          // is command

          console.log("OPTIONS:");
          console.log($.fn.showLinkLocation.defaults);

        } else {
          // is init and options

          options = $.extend(options, arg); 

          console.log("init options: ");
          console.log(options);

          this.filter("a").append(function() {

              return " " + options.leftBracket + this.href + options.rightBracket;

          });

        }

        return this;

    };

  // Plugin defaults – added as a property on our plugin function.
$.fn.showLinkLocation.defaults = {
    leftBracket: "(",
    rightBracket: ")",
    test: "Foo"
};

}( jQuery ));



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.one').showLinkLocation({
    test: "Bar",
    leftBracket: "[",
    rightBracket: "]"
  });

  $('a.two').showLinkLocation({});

  console.log("+++TEST+++");
  $('a.one').showLinkLocation("test");
  $('a.two').showLinkLocation("test");

});
```

As you can see, the second time `showLinkLocation`is invoked, it does not know about the settings made, while the plugin was initialized on the desired element `a.one`.

(HTML code:

```
<a href="http://www.mozilla.org" class="one">Mozilla</a>
<a href="http://www.apache.org" class="two">Apache</a>
```

)

Comment: please add a minimal and verifiable example here, as links can break and the codepen's relation with your question is not evident at first (making things easier for people when asking their help is nice). Plus, your question should point out a specific problem, instead of asking people to write the "good way" for you

Comment: @Kaddath okay :thumbsup:

Comment: @Kaddath what about this? Is it sufficient?

Comment: yes the problem is clearer now, but leads to another question: from what i tested, the code behaves the way i would expect it to do, gets the options when passed some, and uses default values when these are missing. Your "test" case on other hand returns only default options, so that i don't see the point of it. Do you expect that when passing a string (you seem to call it "command") to the function, you get the options as they were when initialized on this specific HTML element?

Comment: @Kaddath My expection is, that I set certain options on initialisation and the in some was stick to the element.

Or how would you solve the problem in this situation and set a different classname for a certain element?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot work in your example because your `options` var is local to the function, when you call the plugin the second time, a new instance of the function is created, that has no access to the first. You need to save these options somewhere.

It's not a good idea to store in defaults (as you seemed to try to do, this is what you display in your tests), because there is only one default and can be many elements.

The cleanest way IMO would be to store them in a javascript array inside the plugin, but it needs a safe identification of the elements that were targets of the plugin, an easier way is to store it directly in the element, using for example jQuery's data (using JSON may be unnecessary here):

```js
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.showLinkLocation = function(arg) {

      var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.showLinkLocation.defaults);

        if (typeof arg === "string" && arg === "test") {
          // is command

          console.log("OPTIONS:");
          
          //RETRIEVING THE OPTIONS FROM THE ELEMENT(s)
          this.filter("a").each(function(){
              options = $(this).data('linkLocationPluginOptions');
              if(options){
                  options = JSON.parse(options);
              }
              console.log(options);
          });

        } else {
          // is init and options

          options = $.extend(options, arg); 

          console.log("init options: ");
          console.log(options);

          this.filter("a").append(function() {

              return " " + options.leftBracket + this.href + options.rightBracket;

          });
          
          //STORING THE OPTIONS IN THE ELEMENT(s)
          this.filter("a").each(function(el) {
              
              //name may look complex, the goal is to be unique across plugins
              $(this).data('linkLocationPluginOptions', JSON.stringify(options));
              
          });

        }

        return this;

    };

  // Plugin defaults – added as a property on our plugin function.
$.fn.showLinkLocation.defaults = {
    leftBracket: "(",
    rightBracket: ")",
    test: "Foo"
};

}( jQuery ));



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.one').showLinkLocation({
    test: "Bar",
    leftBracket: "[",
    rightBracket: "]"
  });

  $('a.two').showLinkLocation({});

  console.log("+++TEST+++");
  $('a.one').showLinkLocation("test");
  $('a.two').showLinkLocation("test");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.mozilla.org" class="one">Mozilla</a>
<a href="http://www.apache.org" class="two">Apache</a>
```